# VBA saving Excel to Sharepoint freezes forever with a screen showing “Getting list of available content types and properties…”

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have VBA that, along with a whole lot of other stuff, saves an excel workbook to SharePoint (enterprise 2010 I think) and it works fine most of the time but every once in while, when a user runs the VBA, the Excel freezes with a pop up showing "Getting list of available content types and properties...". If the user selects cancel another pop up come up "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed. If the user selects 'Debug' the last line of VBA is highlighted as creating the error.

```
Dim fileName As String
Dim excelDirName As String

fileName = [c9]
excelDirName = [c16] & "/"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs excelDirName & fileName & ".xls"
```

Since this works sometimes (and it worked for over 6 months without this happening) and not other times I am not sure what it could be and I am thinking something was updated in SharePoint.

Comment: have you checked `fileName`  and `excelDirName` current values when it errors out?

Comment: Does the workbook have only and exactly one worksheet and workbook structure protection so no one can add a new sheet?

Comment: @user3598756 the values are fine, They only change by different numeric values (time stamp in the file name) between times when it works and other times when it does not.

Comment: @Mat'sMug not understanding the question but due to the workbook has some VBA for saving protections the save command above is actually proceeded by   'Application.EnableEvents = False' to turn that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it a bit differently, so as to make it more robust:

```
With SomeSpecificSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = .Range("SavePath").Value

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = .Range("SaveFileName").Value

End With

Debug.Assert Trim(path) <> vbNullString
Debug.Assert Trim(fileName) <> vbNullString

Dim savePath As String
savePath = path & "/" & fileName

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs savePath
```

Note:

- Be explicit about the worksheet you're reading from - you're currently reading from whatever the active sheet is, and unless every single worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` has the expected values in `$C$9` and `$C$16`, that's asking for trouble.
- Use [named ranges](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64), so that if a user inserts a column before column C or a row before row 9, your code still refers to the correct cells.
- Let `SaveAs` determine the file's extension.
- Use `Debug.Assert` to verify assumptions (and break before you freeze). Alternatively, you can explicitly validate the values, for example:

  ```
  If path = vbNullString Or fileName = vbNullString Then 
      MsgBox "I need a path!"
      Exit Sub
  End If
  ```